# Facebook Graph API returns statuses for only some friends

Tags: facebook

I'm using the Facebook [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to retrieve statuses from friends. Querying `[username]/statuses` returns statuses for myself, and certain friends, but not others. So, for some users, I get...

`{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10152965008840076",
      ...
    }
  ]
}`

But others return only...

`{ "data": [] }`

...Even though, on their profile pages in Facebook, I can see their statuses.

Thinking this might be a permissions problem, I enabled the following permissions, to no avail:

- friends_actions.news
- friends_activities
- friends_status
- read_friendlists
- read_insights
- read_mailbox
- read_requests
- read_stream
- user_activities
- user_status

Why do some users return statuses, but not others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get statuses, one should only need `read_stream` permission as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status

> Reading a user's status messages requires the `read_stream` permission.

Without the id of the user's friend it's not possible to know the exact reason of the cause. Possible things to look at what would be

- The friend has the platform disabled in their settings (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=opt_out&view)
- The friend has no status objects but post objects instead so the data will appear in [username]/posts with `read_stream` permission
- Permissions were never actually set in your app, this happens when developers assume "Configuring Permissions" in app settings is where to set permissions. An easy way to debunk this would be a call to `/me/permissions`

If all of the above were checked then send a detailed bug report to developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: The user has statuses which are not posts, activities, etc., visible from the `[username]/feed` endpoint.

Since I'm only using only the [graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) for the moment, I set my permissions through my access token. Does the graph API explorer count as an app for which I need to set app permissions?

It's possible the user has disabled sharing statuses. Will verify and report back.

Comment: @garbados Cannot really say for sure what the problem could be without knowing the user id or the actual object id that appears on the wall of the user

Comment: Verified, the user in question had set permissions such that their statuses cannot be accessed from the API except on their behalf. Accepting your answer.

Comment: Great answer! Didn't know about this "platform on/off" setting!